# Using Navigation Components the onCreateOptionsMenu method called on Fragment on backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, navigation, navigationcontroller

I am using Navigation components to move between fragments.  I created a Fragment superclass used by all fragments with the following:

```
var hideMenu = false

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    menu.clear()
    if (hideMenu) return
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.standard_menu, menu)
    ....
```

On the main/start fragment logic sets hideMenu to true true so no menu displays. Good so far.

The user can click a number of different buttons to display other fragments that do not override hideMenu. The problem is that right after the 'target' fragment onCreateOptionsMenu is called ( hideMenu = false so the menu is inflated), the main/start onCreateOptionsMenu method is called. And since it has hideMenu = true, the menu is cleared. Bad, bad, app.

I see from other StackOverflow questions the navigation component supposedly replaces not adds fragments to the backstack. Is this not the case for the main/startup fragment? If so, any words of wisdom to get around this problem?

Comment: Why are you calling `menu.clear()` at all? That's never something you need to do for Fragments.

Comment: I am trying the one activity, multiple fragments architecture  - along with using Navigation components.  The fragments use the same menu, but the fragment may need to remove a menu option if that option is for the fragment currently being shown. I figured the best thing to do was to clear the menu on each fragment and have a small bit of code as needed in some of the fragments to tailor the menu options. I was liking navigation components until I ran into this problem. Now may just strip out navigation components and do it old fashion way.

Comment: Every time `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called, the menu is being recreated from scratch - there is nothing to manually remove since there's no previous state that exists. Please remove `menu.clear()` and rewrite your question to show what problem you're having when you do that.